# newbie Django form not valid

Tags: django, forms, select, menu, arguments

i have this `form.py`:

```
class specForm(ModelForm):
    a = Doctors_list.objects.values_list('specialty', flat=True)
    specialty = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=a)
    class Meta:
        model = Doctors_list
```

and this `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from testApp.forms import specForm

def specForm (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = specForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = specForm()
    return render_to_response('hello.html', {'form':form})
```

When i run it i get the folowing error: `specForm() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`
, i suposse it's because it considers the `form`not valid, why? How i fix it?

my models.py:

```
class Doctors_list(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    specialty = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    hp_id = models.ManyToManyField(Health_plan)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a name conflict between the method `def specForm(request)` and the actual object form `class specForm`. Try to rename one of these. My recommendation is to rename the method because it might be call from within `urls.py` only.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Don't give your form class and your view the same name.

[By convention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/), your form should be named `SpecForm`, your view `spec_form` (or even better, something like `update_specialty`), and your model `Doctor`.